# Custom Categorical_Crossentropy Loss

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, loss-function

I'm attempting to create a custom categorical loss function in TensorFlow for experimental purposes. However, when I use the custom loss function, the performance of my model differs from when I use TensorFlow's built-in `categorical_crossentropy` as the loss function. Here is my code snippet:

```
def CustomLoss(y_true, y_pred):
    usual_loss = tf.keras.metrics.categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred, from_logits=False, label_smoothing=0.0, axis=-1)
    return usual_loss

model.compile(
  loss= CustomLoss,
  optimizer='adam',
  metrics=['categorical_accuracy']
  #run_eagerly = True
    )
```

I have tried experimenting with gradient calculations, but the results remain the same, suggesting that TensorFlow's default gradient handling doesn't appear to be the issue.

What modifications should I make to my custom loss function to achieve performance consistent with the built-in `categorical_crossentropy`?

Comment: Differs how exactly? You always need to be very detailed on the problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am experimenting this on an InceptionV3 CNN architecture. When I am providing the built in keras loss i.e., loss = 'categorical_crossentropy' in model.compile, I am getting good results with around 95% accuracy. But when I am trying to use a custom loss function with the same technique, I am getting very low accuracy. That's the problem.

In-short, I am trying to implement categorical_crossentropy through a user-defined (custom) loss function.